# What this mean "Only fully matched bundles can be simulated" for mev_simBundle of flashbots?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, flashbots

I look at flashbots' mev_simBundle method explanation as follows:

This method has similar arguments to mev_sendBundle, but instead of submitting a bundle to the relay, it returns a simulation result. **Only fully matched bundles can be simulated**

What does this statement mean, because when we call the mev_sendBundle method to simulate a trade, sometimes the simulation succeeds and sometimes it fails for the same bundle, why is that?